# Can't restore iTunes backup

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, restore

I've got a device (iPhone 7 Plus) with iOS 14.3 to which I did a backup about a month ago on a Windows 10 laptop with iTunes. I can't remember if it was on iOS 13.7 or iOS 14.3, as the same day I did the update to it (it's not my phone, and the user didn't update earlier). After the update to iOS 14 I did a reset to the phone for different reasons, and now I can't get the data back.

The problem is that I can't restore the backup I did, as at the end of the restore it says "the iPhone couldn't be restored because it disconnected". Tried with different iTunes versions, including the latest one. Just when it's supposed to end the process as the bar of the restore fills, it throws the error of the screenshot I put below. I've tried with two different computers (obviously transferring the backup to the second one and with enough space on all the devices, including the iPhone) and with different cables, even with Apple ones without success. The process of the restore goes well until the end (during the process the iPhone says it's being restored), that throws that error.

I was thinking about downgrading the iPhone to 13.7, as maybe the backup was made for that version, but for what I've searched I can't downgrade because 13.7 it's not signed anymore.

Any help is so appreciated, as the data that was on the smartphone is very important for his owner. Thanks in advance

[image: Image of the error at restauration]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) As for your question, can you clarify this sentence: *"The process of the restore goes well until the end (during the process the iPhone says it's being restored), that throws that error."*. What do you mean by it goes well until the end? Does it seem to get close to 100% complete or...? Also, I notice you added the 'iTunes' tag to your question - does this mean you're using iTunes on older Macs to try restoring, or are you using a Windows PC? If you can clarify that and the versions of iTunes and macOS or Windows that'd be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've updated the post acordingly

Comment: Note that the backup/restore process is not tied to the iOS that was on the phone at the time. It will always restore to the latest iOS. idk what the exact issue is, but it's not the iOS version.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be tied to the iOS version, but I put it just in case it was the problem. So that lets me even more confused

Comment: Check you have the latest iTunes - seems to be 12.10.10 for Win - https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes because the iTunes version itself needs to be 'correct' to understand the iOS version it's handling.

Comment: I'll give that a try asap, but on the laptopt I did the backup and tried the restore for 1st time, I would swear it was on the latest iTunes.

Comment: Tried with the latest iTunes, having same error

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating the question. @Tetsujin is correct that the iOS version will be irrelevant in this situation. Can I ask what state the iPhone is in at the moment? What I mean is that you've upgraded it to iOS 14 and have since reset the phone. So, which "reset" option did you go through? And, is the iPhone in a totally reset state like it would be when brand new, or has it been set up as a new iPhone, or...?

Comment: It has been setup with an iCloud account (not the same as previous), but I also have being trying with the option to restore at the smartphone's first launch after reseting, and got reset by the settings of the phone itself, at Settings>General>Soft reset(or something similar, got it on my language, not in English)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't let you restore to a different Apple ID. The entire idea is that the ID==the owner, so it's like trying to take someone else's data as far as the phone is concerned. Start from Restore iPhone rather than Restore backup.

Comment: Same error, thanks for your help. Also, as I mentioned above, I tried to restore it before putting any iCloud ID, but with this result, so I think the problem is not the Apple ID